# how to place the text in the bottom center

Tags: android, textview

**how to place the text in the bottom center?**

my implementation

```
 @Override
            protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

                Paint strokePaint = new Paint();
                strokePaint.setARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);
                //strokePaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);


                strokePaint.setTextSize(20);
                strokePaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
                strokePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                strokePaint.setStrokeWidth(5);

                Paint textPaint = new Paint();
                textPaint.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
                //textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
                textPaint.setTextSize(20);
                textPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

                canvas.drawText("Some Text", 100, 100, strokePaint);
                canvas.drawText("Some Text", 100, 100, textPaint);

            }
```

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/img_1" />

<vbright.usanin.salesRegion.Text.TextViewOutline
    android:id="@+id/myImageViewText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/myImageView" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `RelativeLayout` to position your text wherever you want. In your case `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` and `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` do magic.

```
<RelativeLayout  
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:paddingTop="5dip" > 

  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtExistingService"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
 </TextView>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: canvas.drawText("Some Text", 10, 50, textPaint);  ;)

Comment: you can draw text using canvas. but consider various device screen size. I recommend to use relative layout because you can position your text at exactly parent bottom centre. But the decision is yours

Answer (score 2):

You can use like below code

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dip"
        >

    <Button 
        android:text="Bottom Center" 
        android:id="@+id/choose" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

 <LinearLayout />
```

Answer (score 1):

The most simple answer just click `"gravity"` on your imageView attributes and check `"bottom"` and `"center_horizontal"`.